# How to create a UIButton similar to type .system?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How to create a `UIButton` with tap effect similar to `UIButton(type: .system)`, but without specifying `.system` type?

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
// How to set the tap effect?
```

How to set the tap effect which blinks the text when tapped?

Comment: This is already answered and accepted. So why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `UIButton` subclass and override `isHighlighted`:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get { return super.isHighlighted }
        set {
            guard newValue != isHighlighted else { return }

            if newValue == true {
                titleLabel?.alpha = 0.25
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                    self.titleLabel?.alpha = 1
                }
                super.isHighlighted = newValue
            }

            super.isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily declare you own custom class as the following

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setTitleColor(self.titleColor(for: .normal)?.withAlphaComponent(0.5), for: .highlighted)
} }
```

Comment: Perfect , I tried and worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the button to be of type system then set the frame

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
btn.frame = .zero
```

Comment: I would like to know how to get the `.system` like effect.